# Pass custom parameters to ExtJS View controller

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, parameters, controller

In ExtJS 6.02, if I have something like this:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.foo.Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'foo',
    controller: 'foo',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'CLICK HERE',
        handler: 'onAdd'
    }],
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.foo.FooController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.foo',

    onAdd: function (my_bool) {
        console.log(arguments);
        
        if (my_bool === true) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'We have been rendered');
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('MyApp.view.foo.Foo', {});
```

Is there a way to pass different parameters than the defaults to the controller method?
In the example above the controller would only receive a single boolean value.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dgr

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to what you want here.  Your `handler` for the button will always pass its default params to your function, unless you overrode the button `click` event.  It almost sounds like you should abstract your handler logic, put it in its own method, and call that instead.

Comment: @incutonez Yes, overriding would be an option. This method passes 7 parameters in total, but I'm only interested on parameter 1 and 6. So I was looking for a way to only pass those 2. Also, from parameter 2, I only want something inside it, so if I could also only take it, it would be even better.

Comment: I don't think you should override the click event like that... That seems very wrong.  I'd recommend abstracting out your handler's logic into its own method.

Answer (score 0):

How about you adjust your handler?
If you define your own function there you can also define your params you want to pass to the viewcontroller.

```
handler: function(btn) {
        btn.up('panel').getController().onAdd('param1', 'param2');
    }
```